# Make individual elements in a list mandatory, only if the user fills at least 1 attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

So, I have this ViewModel mapped to my View (just an example):

```
ContactViewModel{
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public List<Friend> FriendList {get; set;}

    public class Friend(){
        public String Name {get; set;}
        public String Email {get; set}
        public String Gender {get; set;}
    }
}
```

And these are the requirements:

1. The user can fill from 0 to N items in the list of friends.
2. Once the user starts filling the first (the first field could be any of the three) field of a Friend information (Name, Email, Gender), all of the other fields become mandatory.

Is there an easy way to solve these requirements with attribute validation in the view model? (both, server and client side).

**Edit:**

I don't want to use something like RequiredIf( ) because my code will look like this:

```
public class Friend(){
    public String Name {get; set;}

    [RequiredIf("Name", NotNull)]
    public String Email {get; set}

    [RequiredIf("Name", NotNull)]
    [RequiredIf("Email", NotNull)]
    public String Gender {get; set;}
}
```

So, if Friend has 20 attributes, the last attribute will have 19 RequiredIf attribute validator. And the worst part is that the client side validation won't work, because the attributes wil override each other.

Comment: Personally I would not even bother going server side validation with what you have to do,  to me it more a client side validation that can be achieved with simple JavaScript,  for the serverside you must include your own custom validation

Comment: there are a few libs that have DataAnnotations that will fit this validation, https://foolproof.codeplex.com/ has a `RequiredIf` that would work, its open source so you can just grab the bits you need if you don't want to add the package, https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations is also a great lib that can allow complex validation rules. e.g `[RequiredIf("Name != string.Empty")]`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I have the RequiredIf validation in my project right now. But I don't think it will work in this case, because "Friend" actually has more than 20 parameters, the code will be a mess because RequiredIf is a per attribute validator.

Comment: @cacho, what do you mean by a mess, if all the other fields are required if `Name` is set then just add `RequiredIf` to the other fields, or am I misreading the question.

Comment: @cacho, ohhh I thought if `Name` was entered ALL other fields were mandatory, If I understand correctly what you need is if `Name` is filled out then `Emai`l is mandatory, if `Name and Email` are filled out then `Gender` is mandatory etc? may I ask why this type of validation is needed, for example why would `Gender` rely on `Email`? Cant all fileds just have one attribute 'ReqiredIf("Name", NotNull)]` ?

Comment: Actually, it does not depend on Name attribute. The idea is, if ANY attribute is completed, then all of the rest of the attributes should become mandatory. @sa_ddamn213